# Android Studio not executing, it only shows splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio not executes the IDE, it only shows the splash screen, after few seconds, it dissapears.

I tried the following solutions:

- I uninstalled the program and installed again
- I restarted my PC after installation
- I added "JAVA_HOME" and "JDK_HOME" as environment variables
- I checked if "studio.exe" process is executing, if IDE is executing in background.
- I executed Android Studio as "Administrator"
- I disabled Antivirus temporarily
- I deleted ".android", ".AndroidStudio", ".gradle", ... folders

These solutions not worked.
Which is the problem with execution?

Comment: *after few seconds, it dissapears.* does it complete the loading process?

Comment: No, loading process not starts, only shows the splash screen and after few seconds, it dissapears

Answer (score 1):

- If you have done this:

do you have installed the `JAVA SDK` donwload the latest release from **[here!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)**
be sure to have configured the `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` in your environmet variables.

- then check the .log file generated by `Android Studio` to get more information about your issue:

  **C:\Users[MyUser].AndroidStudio1.2\system\log\idea.log**

Comment: I deleted all folder that starts with dot for try to resolve the problem, and not worked

Comment: In my case, wasn't because of java, but checking the log file did help!

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced this issue as well.

It was related to me having dual monitors and oddly the secondary screen was not able to load android studio.

In my setup the issue resolved itself once the secondary screen was made the primary screen ( I have an ATI graphic card 8300) with Android Studio 2.3 and Canary build 3.x

Answer (score 0):

This is typicaly a low memory problem. I currently have the same and I was able to make few correlations. If you start your task manager, you will notice that "Disk" goes to ceiling when starting Android Studio. Actually, you will surely notice that it goes more often to 100% that you'd expect and Android Studio is just the perfect vector to observe this, since it consumes a lot of resources.

The annoying part of the answer is that this "Disk 100%" bug on windows 8.1 is really widespread and solutions doesn't seem that straightforward. For the record, if I find my cause (or if I'm all wrong in my hypothesis), I'll keep you posted.

Regards